# Why executing std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C") at startup?

Tags: c++, utf-8, localization, locale

Cppreference.com [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale):

> During program startup, the equivalent of std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); is executed before any user code is run.

Calling `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");` sets the current locale to "C": basically a special, minimalistic locale where strings are seen as simple chunk of bytes, no knowledge of characters and so on.

This obviously affects how locale-dependent functions work (e.g. `fprintf`, `tolower`, ...). Why is that? Should I revert the locale to something else if I want to work with UTF-8 strings in my program?

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages in your question.

Comment: What locale state should the program default to if none is set in the program ?  Remember this needs to be the default on all implementations, otherwise it would need to be Implementation Defined and you would have to search your implementation docs.

Comment: @RichardCritten so programs don't inherit the current locale set by the operating system?

Comment: Does the C/C++runtime support the OS's locale, it could be a barebones system, or just a locale for which the library maintainers have not provided one.  The runtime library just needs a sensible default that works on __all__ systems.